# What is wrong with my solution to this equation : $346 x+ 1250 \equiv 49 \pmod{105}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I'm not sure how to get $x$ but with my way $x = 39$. The solution for $x$ is 29 though. Could anyone possibly help me with the calculating method?

Mine:

$\gcd(346,105) = 1 \Rightarrow  x = a^{-1} \cdot b \pmod m \Rightarrow  346^{-1} \pmod{105} = 61 \Rightarrow  (61\cdot49)+1250 \pmod{105} = 39$

Comment: You have to multiply by $61$ the quantity $49-1250$.

Comment: Also try to solve it by CRT.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way you isolate $x$ in the equation, especially the $1250$ term. Starting from
$$346x+1250 \equiv 49\pmod{105},$$
you need **first** to substract $1250$ on both sides, and only **then** to multiply both sides by $61$ (the inverse of $346$ modulo $105$). This gives you
$$x\equiv (49-1250)\cdot 61\equiv 59\cdot 61\equiv 3599\equiv 29 \pmod{105}.$$

As an aside, you would also probably make your life a bit easier by simply reducing the numbers a little bit. $346\equiv 31\pmod{105}$ and $1250\equiv 95\pmod {105}$, so the equation is equivalent to
$$31x+95 \equiv 49\pmod{105}.$$

Comment: I preferred your previous edit to be honest, but I have run out of votes to give anyway.….Much better :)

Comment: @user477343 I decided to edit this way to emphasize that the problem with OP's computation was really about the order in which the operations were performed. I thought the simplification of the factors was a bit distracting from that point of view.

Comment: I just like answers that don’t skip too many steps. I think it is much more clearer and requires less thinking for those people who read through answers and like to double-check whether or not they are indeed correct (like me).

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$346x+ 1250 \equiv 49 \pmod {105} \iff 31x \equiv 59 \pmod {105}$$

thus since $gdc(31,105)=1$ we can find the inverse of $31 \pmod {105}$ by Euclidean's algorithm.

As an alternative by CRT we get

$$\begin{cases}31x \equiv 59 \pmod {3}\iff x \equiv 2 \pmod {3} \\31x \equiv 59 \pmod {5} \iff x \equiv 4 \pmod {5} \\31x \equiv 59 \pmod {7} \iff 3x \equiv 3 \pmod {7} \iff x \equiv 1 \pmod {7}  \end{cases}$$

thus

- $ x \equiv 1 \pmod {7} \implies x=1+7k$
- $x=1+7k \equiv 4 \pmod {5}\implies 1+2k \equiv 4\pmod 5 \implies 2k
     \equiv 3\pmod 5 \\\implies k \equiv 4\pmod 5 \implies x=1+7(4+5h)=29+35h$
- $x=29+35h \equiv 2 \pmod {3} \implies h\equiv 0 \pmod 3$

thus $$x=29 \pmod {105}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $346\equiv 31$ and  $1250\equiv -10\mod 105$, so the congruence really is
$$ 31x\equiv 49+10\mod 105. $$
Now the  *extended Euclidean algorithm* yields $31^{-1}\equiv 61\mod 105$, so the solution is
$$x\equiv 61\cdot 59=60^2-1\equiv 29\mod 105.$$

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing I would do is reduce the coefficients (mod 105)!  346= 3(105)+ 31 so 346= 31 (mod 105) and 1250= 11(105)+ 95 so 1250= 95 (mod 105).  The equation is equivalent to 31x+ 95= 49 (mod 105).  Then subtract 95 from both sides: 49- 95= 49+ 105- 95= 59 so 31x= 59 (mod 105).

That is the same as saying that 31x= 59+ 105y for some integers x and y.  31x- 105y= 59 is a "linear Diophantine equation" and there is a simple way of solving such equations- the "Euclidean Algorithm".  First look at the equation 31x- 105y= 1.  31 divides into 105 three times with remainder 12:  105- 3(31)= 12.  12 divides into 31 twice with remainder 7: 31- 2(12)= 7. 7 divides 12 once with remainder 5: 12- 7= 5.  5 divides into 7 once with remainder 2: 7- 5= 2.  Finally, 2 divides into 5 twice with remainder 1: 5- 2(2)= 1.  Replace that "2" with 7- 5: 5- 2(7- 5)= 3(5)- 2(7)= 1.  Replace that "5" with 12- 7: 3(12- 7)-2(7)= 3(12)- 5(7)= 1.  Replace that "7" with 31- 2(12): 3(12)- 5(31- 2(12))= 13(12)- 5(31)= 1.  Replace that "12" with 105- 3(31): 13(105- 3(31))- 5(31)= 13(105)- 44(31)= 1. So one solution to 31x- 105y= 1 is x= -44, y= -13.  But it is easy to see that x= -44+ 105k, y= -13+ 31k is also a solution: 31x- 105y= 31(-44+ 105k)- 105(-13+ 31k)= -1364+ (31)(105)k+ 1365-(105)(31)k= 1.

We want a positive solution so take k= 1: x= -44+ 105= 61. 31x= 1 (mod 105) is satisfied by x= 61: 31(61)= 1891= 18(105)+ 1.  Finally, to solve 31x= 59 (mod 105), multiply by 59: x= 61(59)= 3599= 34(105)+ 29.  x= 29 satisfies 31x= 59 (mod 105).

Checking in the original problem: 346(29)+ 1250= 11284= 107(105)+ 49= 49 (mod 105)